# Software User Personas

Tags: user-experience

I work for a small startup, < 10 employees. Each of them comes from a very different industry and most are not engineers. This, as you can imagine ignites argument after argument that our product should not do feature X because industry Y doesn't to it however we must do feature Z.

After working for a few other startups I learned that creating persona's is a great way to unite the team toward a creating a cohesive, focused product.

My question is does anyone have any experience creating user personas with a limited customer base?or have any tip's for creating good personas?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon do a thing which I thought was good.

Get the team to write, and agree on, the press release for you product or feature before you start.

Obviously the press release is about selling the  product. It has to say why its great and why *you the user* need it.

Once you have this it sets a baseline of what you are trying to achieve through out the project.

When an argument comes up you can refer back to the press release to see which solution matches it.

If the project hits technical problems, say slow performance, which might not have a specific requirement, you can ask 'will this product be as good as the press release says?'

Comment: The technique you're describing is very similar to *readme-driven development*: think about your unique selling points before you think about functionality.